# Formatting off the side

Tags: bug

[How to fix the access issue with Timer JobDefinition Page - SP2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60927/how-to-fix-the-access-issue-with-timer-jobdefinition-page-sp2010)

This question for me is way off to the side of the page. I am using IE9. Chrome and FireFox work fine.:
[image]

Comment: Still broken? Tried with IE9 just now and it rendered just fine.

Comment: Works for me - IE10.

Comment: I clear cookies and temp files and use inprivate browsing and everything works until I log in, I refresh and it all moves to the side like in the picture above. Is it me? It's only for this question.

EDIT: Same exact session in IE. Its broken, then I log out and it's back to normal. Log in and it's broken again. ?